# Build a report / Dashboard in SalesForce

Tags: salesforce, report, dashboard

We have recently integrated our telephony system to SalesForce and we want to make a dashboard that calculate amount of received calls by an agent devided by created lead per agent.
So basically, we have two tables , Calls data and Leads. 
Is this possible to do in SalesForce? The two tables both come with Agent name and Date. thank you very much